# Too few parameters, update statement using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, parameters, pyodbc

```
crsr.execute("UPDATE stock SET stock_amount = ? WHERE stock_Product = ?", amount, int(item))  
cnxn.commit() #Updates stock amount  
crsr.execute("""SELECT * FROM stock""")   
rows = crsr.fetchall()
```

whenever I run this it says there should be 4 parameters

Comment: Why the triple quotes?

Comment: more context would be great e.g table definition.

Comment: Welcome Emily, can you include the full error text as well?